# How to add a “line break” to flexbox, without causing a double-sized gap?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox that uses `gap` for spacing, which needs to support “line breaks” that cause subsequent flex items to jump down to the next row.

All examples I’ve seen suggest doing this with a new flex item that has `flex-basis: 100%` (see example below), however that will cause a double-sized gap between the rows, unlike other rows caused by normal item wrapping.

[image: An demonstration of two flexbox rows, each with three items. The rows have twice the gap between them as the columns.]

Example:

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

I’ve tried adding negative top/bottom margins to the line break item, however that doesn’t have any effect for some reason.

Is there a way to add a line break with the same size gap as other lines?

(Swapping `gap` for margins on the individual items is not an option in this case.)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Added example code to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Appears this just can’t be done currently using `gap`, so you have to establish the gap using bottom margins on the flex items instead.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  column-gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `gap` property is shorthand for `row-gap` and `column-gap`. This means that you can provide two values for gap, thus equalizing row and column distance:

```
gap: 5px 10px;
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 5px 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="break"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah but that would cause half-sized gaps whenever the items are wrapping naturally. The manual break gaps need to match the normal wrapping gaps.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I can find for this is to use `gap` only for gaps in the flow direction (horizontal in this case), and use vertical margin to control vertical spacing.

This feels clunkier than using `gap`, but by adding negative margin on the flex container (to compensate for the margin on the items) achieves the desired effect without side effects (eg. undesired spacing at the top and bottom):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 0 10px;    /* Only use gap for horizontal spacing */
  margin: -5px 0; /* Compensate for item margin */
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0; /* Add (0.5 * gap) vertical margin to flex items */
}
```

As a side note, I'm surprised that negative margin on the `.break` element doesn't work: I'd expect you could solve this by adding `margin-top: -10px` to it, but that doesn't seem to work.

**Edit:** Sorry, I missed that last line that "*Swapping gap for margins on the individual items is not an option in this case*" I'll leave this up just in case the additional step of adding negative margin to the container to compensate for the item margin makes this approach feasible though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gap: 10px;` sets `10px` of gap both vertically and horizontally. You can use `gap: 5px 10px;` for `5px` of vertical gap and `10px` of horizontal.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 5px 10px;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.break {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <span class="break"></span>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```